# Is $(∃x,∃y,¬P(x, y))$ true or is $ (∀x,∀y,¬P(x, y))$ true when $P(x, y) : x^2 > y^2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm taking a discrete structures class and I positively don't understand a thing. I have to verify if this statement is true and prove it. I never know where to start.

Considering $P(x,y): x^2 > y^2,$ is the conjunction of $∃x∃y¬P(x, y)$ and $∀x∀y¬P(x, y)$ true?

My understanding is; $∃x∃y¬P(x, y)$: There exists an x and a y for which P isn't true? Is it what the negation symbol does here?

And then; $∀x∀y¬P(x, y):$ For every x and y, P isn't true?

I really don't get it.

Comment: You're exactly right so far.

Comment: But it makes no sense, clearly there are values x and y can take to make the statement true. Also, if those two propositions are in conjunction, the 2nd one kind of implies the first, no?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. The first one is true. The second one is false. You should prove only the first. Presumably, you should give a counterexample to the second.

Comment: Oooooh, right. Thank you! So the implication would be false, since the first proposition is true and the 2nd one is false? Could the proof be as simple as picking values that validate/invalidate each proposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the case that $$\forall x\forall y, \lnot P(x, y)$$

Take $x = 2, y = 1$. Then there exist, x, y, such that $P(x, y)$ is true since $2^2 \gt 1^2$. Hence, it is not true that $\forall x, \forall y, \lnot P(x, y)$.

And we can surely suppose $x = 1, y=2$, so that $\exists x \exists y \lnot P(x, y)$ because $\lnot(1^2\gt 2^2)$

The conjunction of each claim amounts to evaluating $F\land T$, which is always false.

Comment: You're welcome!